# Return number of rows as decimal

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, data-manipulation

Is there a way to make `COUNT`  return a decimal?

For example:

`SELECT 3 / 5 * 100` returns a value of 0

`SELECT 3.0 / 5.0 * 100` returns a value of 60

If the `COUNT` results are 3 and 5, how can I make the results to store as 3.0 and 5.0?

Comment: Multiply each by 1.0?

Comment: try:
`SELECT 1.0 * 3 / 5 * 100`

Comment: Multiplying by 1.0 helped. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To return a **Decimal** You can:

```
float(3.0 / 5.0 * 100)
```

If you want any variable to be float example
`a = 9`
`print(float(a)`
The result will be 9.0

Hope it help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(15,3)) AS DecimalCount
FROM MyTable
```